# Open rss feed links in a different tab

Tags: jquery, rss

I have an rss feed that i added in jquery as follows:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#rss-feeds").yrss("http://tabnews.co.za/Home/?cat=31&feed=rss2", { image: true, limit: 3 });
            $("#rss-feeds2").yrss("http://tabnews.co.za/Home/?cat=34&feed=rss2", { image: true, limit: 3 })
        });
```

Currently when you click on the link it opens on the same tab,How do i get it to open on a different tab when the links are clicked.
i know that with links in html you can use `target= _blank` will open a new tab.I am not sure how to add it into the above jquery function.

i tried this,which doesnt work

```
$("#rss-feeds").yrss("http://tabnews.co.za/Home/?cat=31&feed=rss2","target=_blank", { image: true, limit: 3 });
```

Comment: `yrss` isn't a jQuery function. Are you using some form of plugin or something?

Comment: yes,using a plugin

Comment: Please add such information: Is it this one? https://github.com/bbClassic/YRSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`YRSS`](https://github.com/bbClassic/YRSS) documentation there is a property called `linktarget` which accepts `_self`, `_blank`, `_parent`, and `_top`. This should allow you to change the target of the link to `_blank` like you want.

Changing your code to the following should work.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#rss-feeds").yrss("http://tabnews.co.za/Home/?cat=31&feed=rss2", { image: true, limit: 3, linktarget: "_blank" });
    $("#rss-feeds2").yrss("http://tabnews.co.za/Home/?cat=34&feed=rss2", { image: true, limit: 3, linktarget: "_blank" })
});
```

Comment: @Sarah Awesome! If you felt like it was a good answer please consider up-voting and accepting the answer. Glad it worked tho!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

option 1:

```
$("#rss-feeds").yrss("http://tabnews.co.za/Home/?cat=31&feed=rss2",{ image: true, limit: 3 ,linktarget: "_blank"});
```

option 2:

```
$("#rss-feeds").yrss("http://tabnews.co.za/Home/?cat=31&feed=rss2", { image: true, limit: 3 }).attr({"target" : "_blank"})
```

Comment: Why do you have a string `"target=_blank"` as your second parameter? Can you provide documentation where that is accepted?

Comment: Actually, I adding my code to your code and I forgot to remote your  **taget* * attribute .
sorry for that